# Can we request a team to add you as a member?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, old-teams

While browsing [Teams<sup>beta</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) version I checked one or two of them and thought that, how can I join one of these teams? But I can't find any link for the same. So my question is. Is there any feature or will be added in future to request a team to add you as a member within a team.

Comment: Well, it seems that the ones open to new members have links for that purpose on their [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/200/turkey).

Comment: But that's limited to specific group and not with all of those teams @CodyGray Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/251/ek%C5%9Fi-s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk) one having the link while [this](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/250/bihe-programming) and many more don't have it.

Comment: Maybe BIHE Programming is not looking for new members? I have no idea what BIHE is.

Comment: Maybe they didn't yet come around to adding a link? However, I would like an indication if a Team is open for "application" or not. Something like "This Team is open to applications." or "This Team does currently not accept applications from everyone." as a switch in the Team preferences.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm talking about @Trilarion

Comment: @Uchiha This feature is in the final stages of being tested. It should hopefully launch in the next few weeks. :)

Comment: Thanks @Hynes for an acknowledgement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is now enabled on production. We rolled it out a few weeks ago when the Developer Story launched in private beta. Anyone though can request to join a team, not just people in the Teams or Developer Story private beta. We've been working on the ability for people to request to join teams for a little bit. Here's how it works:

**Find a team you'd like to join and click the "Request To Join" page above the member list:**

[image: Request To Join]

**Next enter your team role.**

[image: Team Role]

**Now your request has been sent.**

At this point current team members can then approve requests by clicking the "Pending Requests" link in the right sidebar. Pending requests are approved or declined by **a** person on the team. This can be adjusted (the number of approvals required to accept someone on the team). We wanted to see how people use the system first and where we need to react.

### What about the unique URL?

The unique URL still works and we have no plans to take it away. Anyone who clicks on that link bypasses the approval process and is automatically added to the team, irregardless if they have a pending request or if a previous request was denied. Like before, if you click the link — you're on the team.

### What's next?

- In the near-future we'll be adding settings so that a team can turn off the "Request to Join" ability and only use the unique URL.
- Further out, we're exploring the ability for teams to be completely open and have no approval process for members.

Comment: Now wait for people to request to join [team/1](http://stackoverflow.com/teams/1/stack-overflow) :P

Comment: Jokes apart, What about the Link? Are they still valid?

Comment: @BhargavRao The unique URL still works. I'll make a note about that in the post.